# Как сделать доступ к команде через роль

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Писал простые команды и столкнулся с тем, что обычные пользователи могут их использовать, хотя стоит параметр `has_role`.

Код:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="mute", description="Замутить пользователя")
@commands.has_role(1104720197853659259)
async def mute(ctx, member: nextcord.Member,time: int, *,reason=None):
    role = member.guild.get_role(1104714301354283139)
    embed = nextcord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
    embed.add_field(name="Мут выдан", value=f"Нарушитель: {member}\n Время: {time} минут\n Причина: {reason}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ к этому вопросу я не нашел. Но вижу что вы хотите сделать команду мьюта. И
если хотите сделать команду только для участников у которых есть права на мьют, то используйте это `@commands.has_permissions(mute_members=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй эту команду
@commands.has_any_role("#Вписать нужную роль")
или можешь перечислить несколько ("", "") id роли вроде тоже можно воткнуть, но не точно